# Python pause or stop realtime data

Tags: python, stream, export-to-excel

This time I want to know what possible solutions exist to following situation: I let my Laptop read the raw mouse data (Ubuntu OS) with a python script I already posted here. It has a method, which reads the mouse file and extracts the x,y data from it. a while true loop uses this method to put the data into an array. when I use a time counter to stop reading after a while the script puts the data into an excel file. 
What I now need is a option to pause the data stream, i.e. to change mouse position without creating data, and then resume it.  I would like to have something to stop the reading and to write it into excel.

```
import struct
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import xlsxwriter
import time
from drawnow import * 

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('/path/test.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
file = open( "/dev/input/mouse2", "rb" );
test = [(0,0,0)]
plt.ion()


def makeFig():
 plt.plot(test)
 #plt.show()

def getMouseEvent():
  buf = file.read(3);
  button = ord( buf[0] );
  bLeft = button & 0x1;
  x,y = struct.unpack( "bb", buf[1:] ) 
  _zeit = time.time()-test[-1][-1]
  print ("x: %d, y: %d, Zeit: %d\n" % (x, y, _zeit) )  
  return x,y, _zeit

zeit = time.time()

warte = 0
while warte < 20:
 test.append(getMouseEvent())
 warte = time.time()-zeit     

row = 1
col = 0
worksheet.write(0,0, 'x-richtung')
worksheet.write('C1', 'Zeit')
for x, y , t in (test):
    worksheet.write(row, col,     x)
    worksheet.write(row, col + 1, y)
    worksheet.write(row, col + 2, t)
    row += 1
chart = workbook.add_chart({'type': 'line'})
chart.add_series({'values': '=Sheet1!$A$1:$A$'+str(len(test))})
worksheet.insert_chart('D2', chart)
workbook.close()
 #drawnow(makeFig)
 #plt.pause(.00001)
file.close();
```

It would be awesome to have something like "hit space for pause/Unpause. q for end and save" but I have no clue how to do it. Any idea would be nice :)
Oh and I tried to Plot the Data with matplotlib, which worked but it's something for future improvements ;)

Comment: Could you thread the data-collection with something like greenlet and call a switch() from the data-recording thread with a keybind?

Comment: I have not a good grasp on threading so far, but i will look into it. a sample how it could look like would be nice :)

Comment: Greenlet has docs with some examples which may be helpful:  https://greenlet.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#introduction. Also it may be good for you to focus your question on something specific - like (stopping data-collection) and have the plotting and file related parts (separately) it makes it easier to see what your problem is.

Comment: This is probably a good case for `select` or [`epoll`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/select.html#select.epoll).

Comment: I am not sure how select or epoll could help here. it seems to help check whether data i/o is happening or not. if i read it correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example with the standard threading module - I actually don't know how responsive it will be. Also if you want to pause or start input based on a global hotkey, rather than from the script this will depend on your desktop environment - I've only used `xlib` but there should be a python wrapper for it floating around somewhere.

```
import threading
import struct

data =[]
file = open("/dev/input/mouse0", "rb") 
e=threading.Event()

def getMouseEvent():
  buf = file.read(3);
  #python 2 & 3 compatibility 
  button = buf[0] if isinstance(buf[0], int) else ord(buf[0])
  bLeft = button & 0x1;
  bMiddle = ( button & 0x4 ) > 0;
  bRight = ( button & 0x2 ) > 0;
  x,y = struct.unpack( "bb", buf[1:] );
  return "L:%d, M: %d, R: %d, x: %d, y: %d\n" % (bLeft,bMiddle,bRight, x, y) 


def mouseCollect():
    global e
    #this will wait while e is False (without breaking the loop)
    #and loop while e is True
    while e.wait(): 
        #do something with MouseEvent data, like append to an array, or redirect to pipe etc. 
        data.append(getMouseEvent()) 
mouseCollectThread = threading.Thread(target=mouseCollect)
mouseCollectThread.start()
#toggle mouseCollect with any keyboard input
#type "q" or "quit" to quit.
while True: 
    x = input() 
    if x.lower() in ['quit', 'q', 'exit']:
        mouseCollectThread._stop()
        file.close() 
        break
    elif x:
        e.clear() if e.isSet() else e.set()
```

edit: I was missing a `()` after e.isSet

Comment: Hi thanks for helping! I tried the code, but it seems, that i dont get data from the thread. i put a print cmd into getmouseevent() but it printed nothing(its the correct mousefile i read). any suggestions?

Comment: It depends what you want to do with the data, in my example it should just be appended into data - make sure your device ("/dev/input/mouse") is the correct one. You can test it by running getMouseEvent from interactive shell to make sure it returns a result.

Comment: As stated above i checked, if the device is correct. and the method alone gives data. but when in the thread it seems that nothing happens, i did put a print command to check if somethings happening but nothing is printed.

Comment: check that e.isSet() returns True, mouseCollectThread.is_alive() is True.

Comment: Ok thanks for you patience ;) e.isSet() returns false. mouseCollectThread returns true.

Comment: for threading.Event is when e.isSet() is True, e.wait() will return True, and when e.isSet() is False, e.wait() will wait until it is set to True. See https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html - #Event_Objects

Comment: Yay! i inserted e.set() and it works! ok the input part not, but there i have to figure how to fix thin with my standard python. thanks alot!